# Can you add push notification for a PWA using FCM?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

I've created a chat app.  I'd like to add push notifications but from the firebase documentation I'm not sure if push notification works for a PWA.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

I'd like to trigger a push notification by listening to a message collection so that every time a user receives a message, it triggers a web push notification.  In the firebase docs I only see where the admin is sending notifications from the firebase email client, but I don't see where you can automate notifications based on a collection receiving a new message.

1. User receives a message
2. Cloud function listening to the collection triggers a push notification to the recipient
3. The recipient of the message receives a browser alert that they've received a message

The app is a PWA running on a browser...not installed on the device.

Will this work if the screen is locked?
Will it send notifications if the browser isn't open?

Comment: There are too many question in a single post here, so I recommend focusing it more.. A few answers: if the browser running your PWA implements Web Push, you can use Firebase Cloud Messaging to deliver messages to it. On using Cloud Functions, have a look at this first use-case in the documentation: [notifying users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, the jist of the question is if it's possible to push browser based notifications from a cloud function.

Comment: Yes it is. Once you have the token for the app instance, you can send messages through FCM. See the documentation on [accessing the token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token), and the sample on sending a message.